# Cannot get input string from textarea in field

Tags: javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

Trying to grab user's input from textfield when they click on submit button but I am unable to either set the variable within the textfield function (it gets set to blank because there's no updating), and am unable to access the textarea from outside the field node

```
form {
    //other code
    var textField = field("Short description of action") {
        var textArea = textarea {
            prefRowCount = 1
            maxWidth = 400.0
            hgrow = Priority.ALWAYS
            //actionDescription = this.text //does not update value
        }
    }
    buttonbar {
        var statusText = field("Save status will appear here")
        button("Save baby action") {
        actionDescription = (textField.children[1] as TextArea).text
        //actionDescription = textField.textArea //does not recognize
        //actionDescription = textField.text //wrong, "Short description of..."
        action {
            if (actionDescription.isEmpty()) {
                statusText.text = ("Must enter short description")
            } else {
                 //do some work with inputText
            }
        }
   ...
```

Compiler knows the cast will never work but using debugger it seems that the textarea is child #2 or [1] of the textfield, but then I can't call the getText method on this or any of the children.Please let me know why this simple access is giving me trouble--thank you!

Comment: Yes this is how Edvin showed it in the Tornado tutorial here https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/content/part1/7.%20Layouts%20and%20Menus.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it by binding the textArea's textProperty to a string property in the scope of the whole view or of the form, then check that value as being blank!